# Redhat init script best practice

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, init.d, lsb

I want to write an init service script which runs the program as a particular user (and not root). I will then chkconfig this script and install into my production run level.

I could just put a su command in the script but I was wondering if there is a best practise of doing this.

Thanks,
Garry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just `su`.
You won't need the password because the script will initally be running as root.

There's also the `runuser` command.

If you use `/etc/init.d/functions` you can use the `daemon` function which has an option for specifying the user to run as.

I'd personally sway towards the latter all other things being equal.

Comment: This a the prefered solution: stay as close as possible to the way the OS provided initscripts work. Use /etc/init.d/functions. It'll even provide you with green OK and red FAIL messages when starting the initscript.

Answer (score 3):

If you write a redhat-style init script, the `daemon` function has a `--user` option.

```
daemon --user=$runasuser --pidfile="$PIDFILE" $yourbinary $youroptions
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice might be to use sudo, and modify the necessary files to make sure it happens automatically without being prompted for a password. If you don't mind the password being in the script, I think you can do something like

```
 echo password | sudo -S -u username command
```

What are you doing? Maybe there's a better way?

**EDIT**

Thanks TCampbell

Comment: If using sudo, you'd want to add the -u <run as user> and consider using the NOPASSWD option for that user/command combination.

Comment: Well it's currently been run as root so su doesn't require any password (editing of /etc/sudoers will allow sudo to run with a password as well).

But is this the preferred method?

We have some in-house developed software which I want to write service scripts for. I don't want this software to be run as root though (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I strongly advise against using sudo in init scripts. sudo is meant for *users* to do stuff without knowing the root password. Since an init script is run as root anyway, there is no need to use sudo. Sudo will only needlessly complicate things.

Comment: Using sudo in an init script will fail if `requiretty` is enabled in /etc/sudoers (on by default in cent 6 and cent 7)https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/800

Comment: You think echo-ing the password is **best practice**?